# Theme switching in a vue based project with sass

Tags: vue.js, sass

I have a simple sass variables declarations as below

```
$theme-primary-dom: #181818ff
$theme-primary-sub: #29292Bff
$theme-secondary-dom: #FAFAFAff
$theme-secondary-sub: #C4C4C4ff
$theme-primary-sub-transparent: #29292B22
```

This is what I need for dark theme that is a default theme. BUt I want to add a light theme as well. In my brain it is very simple.

```
if .wrapper.darktheme{    
    $theme-primary-dom: #181818ff
    $theme-primary-sub: #29292Bff
    $theme-secondary-dom: #FAFAFAff
    $theme-secondary-sub: #C4C4C4ff
    $theme-primary-sub-transparent: #29292B22
} else {
    $theme-primary-dom: #FAFAFAff
    $theme-primary-sub: #C4C4C4ff
    $theme-secondary-dom: #181818ff
    $theme-secondary-sub: #29292Bff
    $theme-primary-sub-transparent: #C4C4C422
}
```

Now I have no idea how to do this in SASS.
Also, I have

```
<button class="theme__switch theme__switch--light">theme is light</button>
```

in header component
and,

```
<div class="wrapper darktheme"></div>
```

in main app.vue. which increase complecations as the trigger button and the trigger area are in different components.

I can easily get this using jquery of course, But since I am using vue.cli, adding jquery code didn't felt right. I have been searching all over stackoverflow and google for past 3 days but I haven't found a relative solution yet.

Comment: Put alternate theme styles nested inside a `.wrapper.alternate-theme` selector. I actually recently implemented a light/dark theme switch in my vue app, you can take a look if you want. https://github.com/guanzo/suggestion-box/blob/master/client/src/assets/scss/dark-theme.scss , https://github.com/guanzo/suggestion-box/blob/master/client/src/App.vue

Comment: Yeah! I forgot to mention that I am extreamly new to vue and sass both. I have idea about html, jquery, css, This is my very first project in vue/sass, thought to learn something this quarantine, Which is why your github code went right above my head. Sorry Eric Guan.